error running container: from /usr/bin/runc creating container
Inside a running container I am trying to build a container image using buildah (similar to dind).
The running container is based out of ubi8 image and have instructions that installs both podman and buildah.
When the image build starts, it fails for RUN instruction with the below error
STEP 4/6: RUN chmod u+x ./test.sh && ./test.sh

error running container: from /usr/bin/runc creating container for [/bin/sh -c chmod u+x ./test.sh && ./test.sh]: time="2024-07-29T13:42:03Z" level=warning msg="unable to get oom kill count" error="openat2 /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/buildah-buildah1232363409/memory.oom_control: no such file or directory"

time="2024-07-29T13:42:03Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: unable to apply cgroup configuration: open /buildah-buildah1232363409/cpuset.cpus: no such file or directory"

: exit status 1

time="2024-07-29T13:42:03Z" level=error msg="did not get container create message from subprocess: EOF"

Error: building at STEP "RUN chmod u+x ./test.sh && ./test.sh": while running runtime: exit status 1

Is there any additional configuration that needs to be setup inorder to build a container image inside a running container?
buildah version 1.33.8 (image-spec 1.1.0-rc.5, runtime-spec 1.1.0)

Inside of a container is normally a restricted environment, so you need to grant additional capabilities to the "outer" container. That is why you see the cgroup path missing. Google about "nested containers"
